# threejs texturemap UV with independent alphamap

Tags: three.js, texture-mapping

I have a large texture -a photo- and small simple meshes that should display regions of the main texture. These meshes should have an alphaMap, for example a circle.

In the mesh material's texture (PlaneBufferGeometry), I change the UV mapping so it will display the proper region of the main texture. The problem is that the UV mapping is also applied to the alphaMap but I want it independent.

```
const planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(sz.x, sz.y);
let uvs= planeGeometry.attributes.uv;
for (let ix = 0; ix< uvs.array.length; ix++){
    let x = uvs.getX(ix);
    let y = uvs.getY(ix);
    uvs.setXY(ix, x*.5, y*.75);   // just testing
}

const planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    map: imageTexture,
    transparent: true,      
    alphaMap ,
    normalMap,
});
```

Is there a way to change the UV mapping ONLY of the material's map and leave the other maps (alphaMap and normalMap) kind of independent... Or is there some other approach?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One possible option is to add second set of `uv` coordinates to your geometry:

```
// setup new attribute uvs
var uvb = new Float32Array( [
    0.25, 0.75,
    0.75, 0.75,
    0.25, 0.25,
    0.75, 0.25
] );

planeGeometry.setAttribute( 'uvB', new THREE.BufferAttribute( uvb, 2 ) );
```

And modify the material shader to use that set of coordinates for your color map texture:

```
var planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
    side: THREE.DoubleSide,
    transparent: true,
    map: colorTex,
    alphaMap: alphaTex,
} );

planeMaterial.onBeforeCompile = function( shader ) {

    // vertex modifications
    var vertex_pars = 'attribute vec2 uvB;\nvarying vec2 vUvB;\n';
    var vertex_uv = shader.vertexShader.replace(
        '#include <uv_vertex>',
        [
            '#include <uv_vertex>',
            'vUvB = uvB;'
        ].join( '\n' )
    );

    shader.vertexShader = vertex_pars + vertex_uv;


    // fragment modifications
    var frag_pars = 'varying vec2 vUvB;\n';
    var frag_uv = shader.fragmentShader.replace(
        '#include <map_fragment>',
        [
            'vec4 texelColor = texture2D( map, vUvB );',
            'texelColor = mapTexelToLinear( texelColor );',
            'diffuseColor *= texelColor;'
        ].join( '\n' )
    );

    shader.fragmentShader = frag_pars + frag_uv;

}
```

The drawback of this method is that you need a different geometry every time you want to use a different set of uvs. This could pose a performance impact depending on your application.

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/3npf0woh/)

Comment: A good alternative approach :) Where do you find the GLSL segments to modify, such as `#include <uv_vertex>` and `#include <map_fragment>`? I've written custom shaders, but never looked into modifying built-in materials.

Comment: These are referred internally as [ShaderChunks](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderChunk). Now each material uses a different combination of shader chunks, the actual shader program for each of the materials can be found on the [ShaderLib](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderLib).

Comment: Turns out, most of the materials use the same UV/Map ShaderChunk setup, so this approach should work for most of the materials. Which is a plus and, definitely, isn't always the case.

Comment: texture.repeat seems to affect the other maps in the material, see: https://jsfiddle.net/truji7/raq6o38w/30/ (3rd one is with texture.repeat(0.5,.05). It makes not much sense because apparently it's applied only to one texture

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to approach this is to leave the geometry `uvs` alone, and instead use some of the built-in texture transform properties on your photo texture. They are `.offset`, `.repeat`, `.rotation`. and `.center`. You can read a description [in the docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/textures/Texture.offset). For example, if you want to scale your photo texture to 200%, you could use

`imageTexture.repeat.set(0.5, 0.5);`

if you want to move it around:

`imageTexture.offset.set(0.0, 0.7);`

This would only affect the `imageTexture` and it would leave your alphaMap texture alone.

`.rotation` and `.center` work in conjunction if you want to change the origin of the rotation.

Comment: imageTexture.repeat.set(0.5, 0.5) seems to make something similiar (deforming the other maps) althoguh not exactly. Tomorrow I will try to set a fiddle to test cleanly.

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/truji7/raq6o38w/30/, first one is no remapping, second is setting UVs and thirds is with texture.repeat

Comment: @tru7 Oh wow, you're right. Looking at the shader code, it looks like `uvTransform` is generated from the diffuse map texture properties, yet it affects all textures that use `vUV`. That's either a bug, or something that should be in the documentation.